# How to align v-cols horizontally in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to align all seven of those buttons centered. As you can see the last one is a bit off compared to the first one.

[image]

How do I achieve this? 
I've already tried `justify="center"` and `justify="space-around"`

Here is my code:

```
  <v-row no-gutters justify="space-around">
    <v-col v-for="(item, index) in buttons" :key="index">
      <toggle-button
        :weekday="item.weekday"
        :button="item.state"
      ></toggle-button>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Here is the `toggle-button` component:

```
<template>
  <v-btn
    outlined
    depressed
    :class="button ? 'primary white--text' : 'outlined'"
    @click="button ? (button = false) : (button = true)"
    v-model="button"
    icon
  >
    {{ $t("roomservice.weekdays." + weekday) }}
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ["button", "weekday"]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`v-col` is not a flex and contents inside (toggle-button) are justified to start form left.

you can fix this by adding `class="d-flex justify-center"` on `v-col`

```
<v-row no-gutters justify="space-around">
    <v-col 
        class="d-flex justify-center"
        v-for="(item, index) in buttons" 
        :key="index">
        <toggle-button
            :weekday="item.weekday"
            :button="item.state"
        ></toggle-button>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```